# Model binding / ViewModel binding in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Let's start with simple code:

```
public class SomeViewModel 
{
    public int State { get; set; }
}

public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult DoSomething(int state)
    {
        var viewModel = new SomeViewModel();
        
        if(state % 2 == 0)
            viewModel.State = state * 2;
        else
            viewModel.State = state;
        
        return View("MyView", viewModel)
    }
}
```

MyView.cshtml:

```
@model SomeViewModel;

...
    <form method="get" asp-action="BlablaAction" asp-controller="OtherController">
        <input asp-for="State">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

...
```

I'm making requests:

/some/dosomething?state=4 => input value = 4

/some/dosomething?state=5 => input value = 5

/some/dosomething?state=6 => input value = 6

/some/dosomething?state=7 => input value = 7

but according to my logic in DoSomething action it should be:

/some/dosomething?state=4 => input value = 8

/some/dosomething?state=5 => input value = 5

/some/dosomething?state=6 => input value = 12

/some/dosomething?state=7 => input value = 7

My question is: Why input value is assigned to query param instead of property of passed model object...
And second thing I know i can change name of param from state to param1 but maybe there is other way to do it...
I've read 2 books about ASP.net core and haven't encounter anything about that.

Comment: Your issue is you want to change the query parameter?

Comment: No really, I just wanted to know why input in view generated by action method has value from query string and not from viewmodel passed to this view.

Comment: How do you making this request? Are you just typing in browser?

Comment: the "asp-for" tag here is just an input... the value attribute would display.  "State" and "state" are also different variables.  Don't put arguments in the method call.. just use " DoSomething()".... and use [bind(supportsget.... to bind the "State" (or "state") property.  As is, depending on routing it's going to assign something to "state" on receiving the GET.  You're never really using "State" at all.

Comment: I guess the short answer is just put value="@Model.State" in your view... so "<input asp-for="State" value="@Model.State">

Comment: pcalkins - Thank you for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When`<input asp-for="">`label complied to HTML,it get value from ModelState before get value from your viewmodel,so you could clear the value in ModelState

```
public IActionResult DoSomething(int state)

        {
            var viewModel = new SomeViewModel();

            if (state % 2 == 0)
            {
                viewModel.State = state * 2;
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            else
                viewModel.State = state;
           
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Also，you could  keep the codes in controller,and just modify the label:

```
<input type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The State field is required." id="State" name="State" value="@Model.State">
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and simple but good solution

Answer (score -1):

if your form method is "get" inputs send as query string but if you want to post them as form you shoule post your form and assign type "post" to your form method.

```
  <form method="post" asp-action="DoSomething" asp-controller="Some">
        <input asp-for="State">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

in this code State bind to your SomeViewModel if your parameter in action be type of SomeViewModel.